# Create an alert on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a button:

```
var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    $(removeButton).attr('class', 'removeProduct');
    $(removeButton).append(document.createTextNode('X'));
    $(removeButton).data('divId', 'productLine' + numProductsInCart);
```

This works, the button appears.

However, when I try to produce an alert on that button being clicked it doesn't work. I click the button and it doesn't do anything.

Here is what I have got to so far:

```
$('.removeProduct').click(function() {
    alert("Hey");
});
```

Comment: Is the event binded to the element ?

Comment: You have to add the element to the DOM tree before you bind the event handler to it, or use `$(removeButton).click(...)` instead of a selector. Also, since jQuery simplifies DOM manipulation significantly , use it to create the element. E.g. `$('<button />', {'class': ' removeProduct', text: 'X'}).data(....)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are attempting to bind the event handler before your add your button to the DOM. If that's the case, you need to delegate the event handler higher up the DOM tree:

```
$("#someAncestorElement").on("click", ".removeProduct", function() {
    alert("Hey");
});
```

This works because DOM events tend to bubble up the tree from the element at which they originate. You can capture the event at any ancestor element. The [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will check whether the event target matches the selector, and run the event handler if so. Note that if you're using a version of jQuery below 1.7 you will need to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `on`.

Alternatively, you could bind the event handler after you've created the element:

```
$(removeButton).on("click", function() {
    alert("Hey");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.removeProduct').live("click", function() {
        alert("Hey");
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't use `live`, it's deprecated. Unless you're stuck on an ancient version of jQuery `on` or `delegate` is preferred.

Comment: Thanks James I will check it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to select the button (`$('.removeProduct')`) before you have added it to the document (I don't see in your sample code where you're adding it to the document). Can't you use your existing `removeButton` reference when you add the `onclick` handler?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the first bit of code has been run before the second. Otherwise, it has not updated the class of the button to be `removeProduct` and has nothing to bind to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.removeProduct').click(function() {
    alert("Hey");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `on` method:

```
$('<button>X</button>').addClass('removeProduct').attr('data-Id', 'productLine' + numProductsInCart).appendTo('div');

$('.removeProduct').on('click', function() {
    alert("Hey");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9gJPL/1/

Comment: Don't use `live`, it's deprecated. Unless you're stuck on an ancient version of jQuery `on` or `delegate` is preferred.

Comment: Your changes won't work (assuming the element is added to the DOM later). You need to pass a selector to `on` to get it to delegate the event handler.

Comment: @JamesAllardice why `won't` work? why its working on jsfiddle?

Comment: It works in the fiddle because you're adding the element to the DOM before binding the event handler. That's not what the OP is doing by the sound of it. My point was the your current code is not equivalent to the `live` version you had before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add the click handler before appending the button on screen? This code works for me:

```
// Append the button
​$("body").append(removeButton);​

// Now add the handler
$('.removeProduct').on("click", function() {
    alert("Hey");
});
```

Or you can add the handler on the button, before appending:

```
$(removeButton).on("click", function() {
    alert("Hey");
});
```

So now, let's refactor the code a little:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    alert("Hey");
}

var removeButton = $("<button/>")
                    .html("X")
                    .addClass('removeProduct')
                    .data('divId', 'productLine' + numProductsInCart)                    
                    .on("click", clickHandler);

​$("body").append(removeButton);​
```

Hope it helps!